# Run a php script after insert

Tags: symfony

I am working on an application using Symfony 3 and Twig templates. I have created forms using symfony formBuilder. I need to run a php script every time a row is inserted in database. Is there anyway that I can do this ?

Comment: If you use doctrine, read about their event-listeners or entity-listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to run a script, you can use the [Process component of Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

Here is an example of usage:

```
$phpBinaryFinder = new PhpExecutableFinder();
$phpBinaryPath = $phpBinaryFinder->find();

$process = new Process("{$phpBinaryPath} worker.php");
$process->run();
```

You should read the related [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for more insights.

---

Then you want to hook after the flush of doctrine, then use an event listener. It's a class with a specific method that you register as a service.

You need to define a class:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class YourListener
{
    private $persisted = [];
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof YourRecord) {
            return;
        }

        $this->persisted[] = $entity;
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        foreach ($persisted as $row) {
            // Execute your action for the given row
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it as service:

```
# services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\YourListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

Check the related documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Answer (score 2):

yes of course, you can use the Events and Event Listeners https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html or Doctrine Event Listeners and Subscribers https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html